# node-input-validator rules for alpha_spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

Is there are any rules for accepting alpha spaces and is there is any alternate solution?

I have also tried with this regex validation.

```
const v = new Validator(req.body, {
    name: 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/',
});
```

But getting exception for **name = "James Bond"** as

```
The name format is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

After research, I have sorted it out

```
const v = new Validator(req.body, {
    name: 'required|regex:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$',
});
```